# Option to link variable group missing

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/variable-groups?view=vsts), I should see an option to link to a variable group under the Variables tab in my build definition, but I don't see it.

I have a variable group defined, but `Link Variable Group` option does not show up.  I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 15.112.26301.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot is referencing "Build" variables, however the documentation you reference is "Release" variables.  These are two completely different setups in VSTS.

However, the ability to link variable groups in is worked into both Builds and Releases now from within VSTS.  The screenshot below is from one of my build definitions while I am editing it.

[image: Build Variable Groups]

Comment: Thanks I did miss that, but according to the same document: "Use a variable group to store values that you want to make available across multiple **build** and release definitions."

Comment: Actually, I made an incorrect assumption based on your screenshot.  When I am editing a build definition, under my "Variables" tab, I see the ability to link variable groups into my build definition.

Comment: Any idea why I don't see that?

Comment: @P.Mancini I get it, sorry, you had tagged your question VSTS and I never double checked.  You are using TFS (On Prem) and not VSTS (cloud based).  That is why you don't see what I see.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  So are Variable Groups not available in build definitions for TFS on prem?

Comment: @P.Mancini It's an option in TFS 2018. I believe you're on TFS 2017.

Comment: Yes, I'm on 2017.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use the new build definition editor to link variable groups.

Comment: Do you know in what version this was implemented?